# Bootstrap changing margins

Tags: html, css, margin

Is there a way to change the contents margin on the left and right of the screen when the content is displayed on a mobile device?
So that the content has a margin on a desktop and no margin on a phone. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: Sure, with media queries. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, use media queries. With media queries you can say that at a certain width of the screen there should be a certain css activated. For example, when your screen is not more than 400px wide, it should bring the font size back to 10px. Try it with the following code as an example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    p{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As Casper already said, you need to use media queries, El Devoper gave you the link. And if you use bootstrap, **maybe** you must use `!important` to overwrite bootstrap's default properties.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    p{
        margin-left: 10px !important
        margin-right: 10px !important
        //or just use "margin: 0 10px !important" to set margins like this:
        //top and bottom = 0, left and right = 10px
    }
}
```

Hope it's helpful